# Update null columns with custom unique ids

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-scripts

I have a table as below:

```
CtId    CustomerID
1   2600000897685
2   NULL
3   2600000089765
4   NULL
5   2600789657465
6   NULL
7   NULL
8   NULL
```

I need a sql script updating null column id with my custom unique id.
Increment unique number starts from:

```
2900000000001
2900000000002
.
.
```

Comment: I've tried below one.  It is getting conversion issue from int to varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @i bigint  = 2900000000001

update tablename
set customerId = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@i) , @i = @i + 1    
where customerId is null
```

Comment: got this error. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Also want to mention that customerId datatype is nvarchar in the table.

Comment: based on updated info from OP, add a `CONVERT` here `set customerId = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@i) , @i = @i + 1`